# Feats that increase number of spells a wizard adds to his spellbook for free each level

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, character-creation, wizard

Looking for feats to increase number of spells that can be learned for free per level for a wizard.

Answer (score 5):

Collegiate Wizard, on *Complete Arcane* pg 181 (**not** in the feats chapter) allows a wizard to start with 6+Int 1st-level spells in their spellbook, and add 4 new spells to their book each level thereafter.

Comment: this is likely another question... but in your opinion... is it worth a feat to do this? Since a wizard can add tons of spells via copying them from another spellbook at an additional cost? It has me wondering if a feat is worth it to save money on spells.

Comment: @Khaldhool Only in a campaign that will particularly out of its way to limit downtime and/or spell sources, so that the wizard can’t rely on scribing normally. The feat is not worth it just for saving money.

Comment: @Khaldhool relying on scribing also means relying on finding spells in the wild that you can scribe. That means gambling on your DM providing them. Collegiate Wizard will always get you the same benefit.

Answer (score 3):

## Feats that add free spells to a wizard's spellbook

The following feats contain the word *spellbook* and add spells to a wizard's spellbook as a benefit of taking the feat at no cost or time on the part of the wizard.

- The untyped feat **Aerenal Arcanist** (*Player's Guide to Eberron* 20), among other benefits, allows the wizard at level 1 and at each new wizard level to add to his spellbook 1 additional free spell. *Note:* Racial prerequisite (elf); regional prerequisite.
- The untyped feat **Apprentice (spellcaster)** (*Dungeon Master's Guide II* 176), among other benefits, allows the wizard at level 1 to add to his spellbook 1 additional free spell, seemingly of any level. *Note:* 1st-level only.
- The untyped feat **Calishite Elementalist** (*Races of Faerûn* 161) allows the wizard at level 1 to add to his spellbook 2 additional free spells from a narrow list, and at each new spell level add to his spellbook 1 additional free spell from a narrow list.
- The untyped feat **Collegiate Wizard** (*Complete Arcane* 181) allows the wizard at each wizard level to add to his spellbook 2 additional free spells. *Note:* Requires DM's permission; 1st-level only.
- The untyped feat **Favored in Guild** (Cult of the Dragon (*Dragons of Faerûn* 54–5) allows the wizard at each new wizard level to add to his spellbook 1 additional free necromancy spell that he can cast.
- The untyped feat **Favored in Guild** (Eltorchul Academy (*City of Splendors: Waterdeep* 26)) (*Complete Psionic* 151), among other benefits, allows the wizard at level 1 to add to his spellbook 4 additional free 1st-level spells.
- The untyped feat **Favored in Guild** (Fellowship of the Purple Staff (*Champions of Valor* 80–2)) (*Complete Psionic* 151) allows the wizard at each even wizard level to add to his spellbook 1 additional free spell from a narrow list.
- The regional feat **Greyhawk Method** (*Dragon* #315 53), among other benefits, allows the wizard at each wizard level to add to his spellbook 2 additional free spells that he can cast. An alternative and more generous reading allows the wizard at each wizard level to add to his spellbook 4 additional free spells that he can cast. *Note:* Regional prerequisite.
- The general feat **Hin Wandermage** (*Races of Faerûn* 164) allows the wizard at level 1 to add to his spellbook 3 additional free spells from a narrow list, and at each new spell level add to his spellbook at least 1 additional free spell from a narrow list. *Note:* Racial prerequisite (lightfoot halfling).

Also, this DM would also allow the feat **Extra Spell** (*Complete Arcane* 79-80) to be used to add 1 free spell to a wizard's spellbook because, sure, why not?

---

***Note:*** For personal use, I have a document compiling all the official, semi-official, and licensed 3e *and* 3.5e *feats; this search was conducted using that document and limited to official and semi-official feats.*